# View object data in HTML

Tags: javascript

if you can help me out there, I'll be grateful.

```
vitor = {
name:"Vitor",
age: 'yourage',
email:"seuemail@teste.com",
address:"my address",

};
function listContact(person){
//get a div that I need to show the data//
var contentInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('right-content')[0];
contentInfo.style.display = "block";
//search throught the object//
for(key in person){

    contentInfo.innerHTML = person[key];
    console.log(person[key]);

}

}
```

Using console.log and document.write it displays perfectly, but when I assign the object to inner HTML, it displays only the last key of my object. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `contentInfo.innerHTML = person[key];` resets the entire contents to what is being assignrd each iteration instead of appending.

Answer (score 0):

When using `console.log` or `document.write` it appends to the existing text where setting `innerHTML` overwrites the existing value.

Try using `contentInfo.innerHTML += person[key]`

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the `innerHTML` each time, so that only the last value is displayed. You need to use `+=` to concatenate the current value with the previous values. If you want line breaks, you need to add `<br>` each time as well.

```js
const vitor = {
  name:"Vitor",
  age: 'yourage',
  email:"seuemail@teste.com",
  address:"my address",
};
function listContact(person){
  //get a div that I need to show the data//
  var contentInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('right-content')[0];
  contentInfo.style.display = "block";
  //search throught the object//
  for(const key in person){
      contentInfo.innerHTML += person[key] + "<br/>";
      //console.log(person[key]);
  }
}
listContact(vitor);
```

```html
<div class="right-content"></div>
```

However, as [connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo) has mentioned, it is expensive to continuously update the `innerHTML` of an element, as the browser has to repaint the page. Ergo, it will be more efficient to first create the string and then set the element's `innerHTML` to it.

```js
const vitor = {
  name:"Vitor",
  age: 'yourage',
  email:"seuemail@teste.com",
  address:"my address",
};
function listContact(person){
  //get a div that I need to show the data//
  var contentInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('right-content')[0];
  contentInfo.style.display = "block";
  //search throught the object//
  let html = '';
  for(const key in person){
     html += person[key] + "<br/>";
      //console.log(person[key]);
  }
  contentInfo.innerHTML = html;
}
listContact(vitor);
```

```html
<div class="right-content"></div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't keep reassigning to innerHTML. Instead, build the full string, and call it only once. Each time you assign to an element's innerHTML, this is causing a repaint, which is *very* expensive.

Comment: @connexo Thanks for the suggestion.